# Calculate NETWORKDAYS using range of Start Dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Is there any way to calculate NETWORKDAYS using a range for the "Start Date" and a single date for the End Date?

I'm trying to incorporate this as SUMIFS criteria in the following formula:

`=SUMIFS($J:$J,$G:$G,"<"&N3,$H:$H,">="&M3,$I:$I,">="&NETWORKDAYS($G:$G,N3)/30)`

- Column G: Project Start Date,
- Column H: Project End Date,
- Column I: Project duration (in months),
- Column J: Hours per month

M3:U3 = 3/1/18 - 12/1/18

The goal is to apply the formula to M4:U4.

Comment: There aren't 30 workdays in a month.

Comment: I don't think you can use a Range as Start Date.
Maybe an option is to build a Macro to loop over all your start dates, using that particular end date, and sum all of the results.